# EventBridge deletion or EventBridge rule deletion/disable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I have some EventBridge (scheduled trigger) that trigger some lambda and I would like to remove the triggers only.

It seems to me that there are several options:

A. To delete the EventBridge

B. Go to the rules under the EventBridge and **delete** the rule(s)

C. Go to the rules under the EventBridge and **disable** the rule(s)

May I ask:

1. Are option-A and option-B actually the same thing?
2. In Option-C, is the rule disabled forever? Or it will come back up automatically after sometime?

Comment: How did it go? still unclear what are the differences between the three options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are option-A and option-B actually the same thing?

Assuming that option A is about a custom EB bus, then they are not the same. Deleting the bus will fail if there are any rules in it. So **first you have to delete the rules**, and then the bus itself. So option B is only possible.

> In Option-C, is the rule disabled forever? Or it will come back up automatically after sometime?

It will not be disabled forever. You can **enable it when you want**. Also it will not become enabled automatically by itself. You have to do it manually, and create some automation to enable it after some time.